# view для searchModel yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Как сделать собственное view в для searchModel? Не gridView, а собрать самому. Мучаюсь сутки! Вот модель:

```
<?php

namespace backend\models\search;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use common\models\Truck;

/**
 * ArticleSearch represents the model behind the search form about `common\models\Article`.
 */
class TruckSearch extends Truck
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id'], 'integer'],
            [['id', 'type_id', 'name', 'carrying'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Truck::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'type_id' => $this->type_id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'carrying' => $this->carrying,
            'status' => $this->status,
        ]);

        /*$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'slug', $this->slug])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'title', $this->title])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'body', $this->body]);*/

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете в контроллере вызвать конструкцию вида: `return $this->render('/custom-truck', ['myTruck' => $truck]);`. При этом контроллер попытается обработать файл по адресу `.../views/custom-truck.php`, в этом файле вам будет доступна переменная `$myTruck` в которой будет содержаться переданная вами переменная `truck`. Дальше вы можете делать с ней что хотите.

Подробнее о создании view вы можете прочитать в [официальной документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html).